# How to capture photo with existing camera app in android?

Tags: java, android

I need to take photo using existing camera app and store it. I took this code from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is

- `startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`
  is depreciated
- Once i enter the camera app a file is created even if the picture is not taken

What changes should i make so that a file will be created only when an image is captured in the camera app?

Comment: `Once i enter the camera app a file is created even if the picture is not taken` No. Not the camera app creates the file. You are creating an empty file yourself with File.createTempFile(). You do not have to do that. Only a FIle instance will do. You are victim #45678 of this example code.

Comment: `How to capture photo with existing camera app in android?` You know how to do that. Please make a better subject.